# Display text after a certain iterations number

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is what my template currently looks like:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ message.content }}</p>
{% empty %}
    <p>No messages</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine. But the problem is sometimes there are more than 20 messages, so I want to only display the 3 first, then add a "More" button which will display the rest in JavaScript. I will take care of the JavaScritp part afterwards but for the moment I want to print the link "More" after the third iteration.

What is the best way to do this? Initialize a variable to 0 and increment it + check in each iteration? Or is there a special tag that gives the currect number of iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable to indicate number of iteration, which you can use as

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {%if forloop.counter < 4 %}
        <p>{{ message.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ message.content }}</p>
    {%endif%}
{% empty %}
    <p>No messages</p>
{% endfor %}
{% if messages|length > 3 %}
    Link for more 
{%endif%}
```

---

Another way could be slice the list for 3 elements and iterate only over it.

```
{% for message in messages|slice:":3" %}
        <p>{{ message.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ message.content }}</p>
{% empty %}
    <p>No messages</p>
{% endfor %}
{% if messages|length > 3 %}
    Link for more 
{%endif%}
```